# Can someone show the right approach to get below desired output?

Tags: python, user-input

When the user gives wrong input for `tax_rate`, it should ask user the correct input for that variable, but instead it is starting from first, asking the `hr_rate` input which is already received.

```
while True:
    try:
        hr_rate = float(input("Enter Hourly Rate: "))
        emp_ot_rate = float(input("Enter Overtime Rate: "))
        tax_rate = float(input("Enter Standard Tax Rate: "))
        ot_tax_rate = float(input("Enter Overtime Tax Rate: "))

    except Exception:
        print("Invalid entry, please retry")
```

Output:

```
Enter Hourly Rate: abc
Invalid entry, please retry
Enter Hourly Rate: 10.2
Enter Overtime Rate: 20.25
Enter Standard Tax Rate: abc
Invalid entry, please retry
Enter Hourly Rate:
```

The last line should ask for Standard Tax Rate again.

Comment: Write a function?

Comment: yep, an ask-for-a-float function that takes the prompt message and returns a float.  In general, ask yourself what parts are the same and what parts need to be different.  In this case it's just the prompt text.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I tried using function as well, but the problem was that whenever user gives a wrong input, it starts running from first.

Comment: Your `try`/`except` is too broad — so you need to effectively apply it to each input separately (perhaps by creating a generic get input function).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see repetitive code, it is generally the case of defining a function that performs the same task but with the appropriate differences based on the given argument(s):

```
def userInput(variable):
    while True:
        try:    
            user_input = float(input(f"Enter {variable}: "))
            break
        except Exception:
            print("Please enter any numbers")
        return user_input
```

This function will perform the same task but the input prompt will change according to the *`variable`* argument; e.g you can call it with *'Hourly Rate'*:

```
hr_rate = userInput("Hourly Rate")
```

and it will prompt the user with the correct sentence:

```
>>>Enter Hourly Rate:
```

Answer (score -1):

From @Brian's comment above, and at the risk of doing someone's homework for them...

```
def float_input(prompt):
    '''Prompt user with given <prompt> string.'''
    while True:
        try:    
            return float(input("Enter Hourly Rate: "))
        except ValueError:  # Make exceptions as specific as possible  
            print("Please enter any numbers")

hr_rate = float_input("Enter Hourly Rate: ")
emp_ot_rate = float_input("Enter Overtime Rate: ")
tax_rate = float_input("Enter Standard Tax Rate: ")
ot_tax_rate = float_input("Enter Overtime Tax Rate: ")
```